# ListBoxView populated using Linq based on TimePicker Value

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Using WPF C#
Have a TimePicker from Xceed.WPF.Toolkit called TimePicker, want to be able to filter the files that are loaded to a listbox based on the last write time of a file

Question: I would like to limit the files listed based on the logTime variable using Linq and where the files have to match the logTime

Code for population of list box currently

```
private void LoadLogsNoDate(string ldate, string ext)
{        
  string[] logs = Directory.GetFiles(logPath + ldate, ext);
  InitializeComponent();
  logList = new ObservableCollection<String>();
  logList.Clear();

  lbLogs.ItemsSource = logList;
  foreach (string logName in logs)
  {
    string s = logName.Substring(logName.IndexOf(ldate) + ldate.Length + 1);
    int extPos = s.LastIndexOf(".");                    // <- finds the extension
    s = s.Substring(0, extPos);                         // <- removes the extension
    s = s.ToUpper();                                    // <- converts to uppercase
    logList.Add(s);                                     // <- adds the items it finds

   }

   DataContext = this;     
}
```

Need to set the TimePicker value to a logTime variable then use the logTime to filter the list of items that are displayed

Successfully have used this code to get the LastWriteAccess time just need some assistance putting it all together properly

```
 public static void Times(string sFile)
 {
   FileInfo info = new FileInfo(sFile);

   DateTime time = info.LastWriteTime;
   string s = time.ToString("HH:mm tt");
   Console.WriteLine("Last Access: " + s);
 }
```

Comment: Added the question in the post but I would like to limit the files that are displayed by filtering the ListBox items using Linq using the logTime variable

Comment: Only include the files before logTime or after?

Comment: equal to the time int the variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you will want to associate the time with the string representing the log file. Instead of an ObservableCollection you'll have an ObservableCollection. Log would be defined as:

```
public class Log
{
   String LogName;
   DateTime LogWriteTime;
}
```

Creating the collection would call your other function (modified to return the read time):

```
 foreach (string logName in logs)
 {
   string s = logName.Substring(logName.IndexOf(ldate) + ldate.Length + 1);
   int extPos = s.LastIndexOf(".");                    // <- finds the extension
   s = s.Substring(0, extPos);                         // <- removes the extension
   s = s.ToUpper();                                    // <- converts to uppercase

   Log newItem = new Log();
   newItem.LogName = s;
   newItem.LogWriteTime = GetFileAccessTime(s)
   logList.Add(s);                                     // <- adds the items it finds

 }

 public DateTime GetFileAccessTime(string sFile)
 {
   FileInfo info = new FileInfo(sFile);

   return info.LastWriteTime;
 }
```

Now that we have our time stored off, I'm going to assume your TimePicker's SelectedValue property is bound to `FilterTime`. There are two ways to approach the problem of filtering:

1. Bind your view to a separate IEnumerable `FilteredLogs` and do the following in the setter of the `FilterTime` variable:

   ```
   FilterdLogs = logList.Where(l => l.LogWriteTime >= FilterTime);
   ```
2. Use a `CollectionViewSource`. This method is awesome! First, create a `CollectionViewSource` property called `LogsSource`. Change your XAML to bind to this instead of the old ObservableCollection.

   ```
   <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredLogs.View}"/>
   ```

Now, in whatever you have for an Init function (constructor, whatever calls LoadLogsNoData, etc.) write:

```
FilteredLogs = new CollectionViewSource();
FilteredLogs.Source = logList;
FilteredLogs.Filter += CheckAccessTime;
```

This sets up a new `CollectionViewSource` that points to your logList collection, and uses the CheckAccessTime function to determine if a particular log entry should be included in the "View" property (which you previously bound to).

The CheckAccessTime function will look like:

```
private void CheckAccessTime(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
{
    Log logEntry = e.Item as Log;
    if (logEntry != null)
    {
        if (logEntry.LogWriteTime >= FilterTime)
        {
            e.Accepted = true;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Accepted = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to refresh the filter anytime the selection changes. So, in the setter of `FilterTime` write:

```
FilteredLogs.View.Refresh();
```

The second option is, in my opinion, a much cleaner way of accomplishing the task, though it may be a bit more confusing at first. Let me me know if I can clarify anything!

This blog post was greatly helpful in researching the second method: http://uicraftsman.com/blog/2010/10/27/filtering-data-using-collectionviewsource/

MSDN for the filter event: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)